# Single page rendering in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Currently I am using build version from here https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download

I would like to show only one page of pdf at screen in normal mode (not presentation mode).

Navigation between pages would be possible only through toolbar buttons. Scrolling only works for moving the displayed page displayed page.

I found something here https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/8724 , but i don't know how to use it in my website.

Could somebody help me with that? I can't find any example of using single page mode.